Can I use Follow Path constraint to move camera along a curve without using Path Animation?
I want a camera to move along any curve like Circle. The easiest and the most used method I found is, using Follow Path constraint and animating the Offset value. And it works when Path Animation is enabled in curve's Object Data Properties.

However, in Blender manual, it's mentioned that Path Animation is deprecated:

The Path Animation settings can be used to determine how child objects
move along a certain path.


This feature is deprecated, but still available. A more future-proof
method is the Follow Path Constraint.

These quotes indirectly mean that, don't use the Path Animation and instead use Follow Path to achieve same result. But I could not find any single resource where it's taught how to do it. The manual has some steps about F-curves but they seem too technical/complex to understand. And even then I'm not sure if I could actually achieve the same result without using Path Animation.
I also believe if a feature is marked as deprecated, the alternate would definitely exist.
So is it possible to achieve same result by using only Follow Path? If yes, how can I do it?

To have a good starting point, set the cursor at the center of your scene, add a Curve > Circle, scale it by 5 in edit mode.
Clear the transform values of the camera, and set X rot to 90 degrees.
Add to the camera a Follow Path constraint, targeting the circle, Forward -X, Up Z, tick Follow curve and click on Animate Path.

To edit the timing, select the circle, go to graph editor, select the Evaluation Time channel, go to its modifiers tab and edit the Generator Modifier values.
Delete the modifier if you want to maually set keyframes (I to insert a new keyframe, hovering over the graph).

While it animates without using the "Offset" value in Constraint, it appears like it still uses the "Path Animation" in the curve's data properties. If I uncheck it, the animation doesn't work, and Camera moves to cursor again. I really don't understand why they say it's deprecated if we can't disable it. Maybe they mean something different. I'm not sure.
